# Apply ALL templates

Tags: .net, xslt, xslt-1.0

My main xslt file imports a multiple other xslt files, and those xslt files may also import/include 0, 1 or many xslt files (and more levels are possible too)

I'd like a way to, from the main xslt file, call ALL imported/included templates that match a specific pattern (either they have the same name, same mode, same matches, or something else).

I'd like to be able to do this without hard-coding to a specific list of imports (i.e. if you add a new import it should be picked up automatically)

Alternatively, to extract the value of a variable with a given name.

In either case the results should be concatenated together into a single nodeset.
The order of the results is not important and a wrapper element is optional (but  desirable)

Is this possible?

Example inputs:

Main.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:import href="File1.xslt"/>
  <!-- Some rules here, including the solution -->
</xsl:style>
```

File1.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:import href="File2.xslt"/>
  <!-- Some unrelated rules here -->
  <xsl:template name="Things">
    <!-- name could be mode or matches, or the template could be a variable instead -->
    <Something/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:style>
```

File2.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- Some unrelated rules here -->
  <xsl:template name="Things">
    <!-- name could be mode or matches, or the template could be a variable instead -->
    <SomethingElse/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:style>
```

Required output:

```
<xml>
  <Something/>
  <SomethingElse/>
</xml>
```

N.B. in my scenario the content of the required templates/variables will be static, although it would be nice to have a solution where they could contain xslt.

Comment: Tell us what you want to achieve (what's your input and desired output), there may be a way of achieving it that isn't quite so weird.

Comment: +Michael Kay Please see edit

Comment: you've retrofitted a requirement to the code you want to write. I want to know what you REALLY want to achieve.

Comment: Lol, you asked for Inputs and outputs, which is what I gave.

Comment: Each xslt file is a module. The parent knows which modules it needs and how to call them, but nothing of what that module actually does. The idea is to call the outermost stylesheet in a mode which outputs this data. That data can then be used to inform what inputs are required (data from sql) before running the transform again but with the actual data.

Comment: I don't quite follow (not even in light of your answer) -- are you trying to transform an input document *using* all your various XSLT documents, or are you trying to transform the XSLT documents themselves?

Comment: Both. The first step has no specific input. It's an exercise in determining what data is required in the input (some queries could be slow, why run them if the data won't be used?). The 2nd step is a normal transform with an input document

Comment: So basically, you want elements to be processed by every template that matches them, not just one? I think the fact that they're in different XSLT documents is a bit of a red herring here. In which case, the easiest solution is to have every template include a `<xsl:next-match/>` instruction, and use XSLT2 or later. You might be able to do something clever with `<xsl:apply-imports/>` in XSLT1, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the next-match rule. Unfortunately xslt 2 isn't available in .Net, and seemingly never will be :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a slightly hacky way to do this.

```
<xsl:template name="EntryPoint">
  <xml>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:import/@href" mode="FindThings"/>
  </xml>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="FindThings" match="/xsl:stylesheet">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(xsl:import/@href)" mode="FindThings"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="xsl:variable[@name='Things']" mode="FindThings"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="FindThings" match="xsl:variable[@name='Things']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="FindThings" match="xsl:import/@href">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(.)" mode="FindThings"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It outputs the contents of all top-level variables called "Things" within every imported xslt file, no matter the depth of the import.